NRPE locally returns 0, but in Icinga it returns 1?
I have a simple python script to check if a file exists:
[me@myserver ~]$ sudo -H -u nrpe bash -c 'python3 /opt/nagios/nagios-plugins/check_illumio'
[sudo] password for me:
0
[me@myserver ~]$ cat /opt/nagios/nagios-plugins/check_illumio
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os

value = os.path.isfile('/tmp/illumio_working')
if value:
    print("0")
else:
    print("1")

However, in Icinga, I always get the result of "1".

Here's the nrpe plugin:
[me@myserver ~]$ cat /etc/nrpe.d/check_illumio_ven_ctl_connectivity.cfg
command[check_illumio_ven_ctl_connectivity]=/opt/nagios/nagios-plugins/check_illumio

What am I missing here? Can Icinga not read a string value of 0 or 1?
